# Adding Join from another Model using Button (CakePHP)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a Course model and a User model joined by Subscription. I want to create a postLink form helper on the Courses index page that would automatically subscribe the user to that, but I don't know how to pass the parameters correctly. In essence, I want the user to click Subscribe, and have a subscriptions/add form automatically submitted so that the join table has another record.

**My specific question is: How do I use a model in another model's view?**

Here's the Courses index.ctp array from print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Course] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Flying
                    [created] => 2014-01-27 19:05:43
                    [modified] => 2014-01-27 19:05:43
                )

            [Subscription] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [user_id] => 2
                            [course_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Here's my bad postLink in the Course index.ctp view:

```
<?php 

  echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Subscribe'),
                            array( 'controller' => 'Subscriptions', 
                                   'action'     => 'add'            ), 
                            null, 
                            __('Are you sure you want to subscribe to # %s?', 
                            $course['Course']['name'])); 
?>
```

Comment: Should really narrow this down to specific question.  While it might not be your intent, when multiple questions are grouped like this, it reads more like "please program this for me".

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the feedback. I didn't mean for it to come off like that. Edited the question with a bold specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're associated, you can do like you would in the Controller - just don't include the model you're actually in, since `$this` is already that model:

```
$this->AssociatedModel->save($data);
```